# Can't seem to find satellite view in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I have an exercise app on my PC that uses Google Maps. At first I was able to click on satellite view in the map and zoom in to a usable scale. Then somehow the satellite icon disappeared. About 2 weeks later it reappeared. Now it is gone again.

Am I looking at a new Google Map problem? If so how did the satellite view come back once and how can I get it back again?

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't do anything different it's probably just Google changing a few things around.  It's possible the satellite icon was removed for a certain version and then added back later on in another update.

Comment: Is there any way around this?