# Is there a way to return to satellite birds-eye view with latest Google maps?

Tags: google-maps

Using Google Maps with latest Chrome/Win10, two questions:

1. How do I get to overhead satellite photo views?  Currently I just have 'Earth' and 'Map'.
2. How do I get to 'birds-eye' satellite photos views (photos taken from angles)?  (Sorry, that might be the 'bing' term).

Details:
I'm using maps.google.com with the latest Chrome/Win10 (as of 2015-Dec-8), logged into Google. I am looking to see actual satellite images.  The only options are 'Map' and 'Earth' view.  The Earth view is 3D rendered and looks like garbage, completely unusable (... like a Picasso nightmare, the screen is full of 3D blobs with weird geometry and textures..).

Similar question asked before, didn't see a solution:

- [Is there a way to return to satellite view with latest Google Maps?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/49901/is-there-a-way-to-return-to-satellite-view-with-latest-google-maps)
- [Can't seem to find satellite view in Google Maps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/74784/cant-seem-to-find-satellite-view-in-google-maps)

Here were suggestions on previous posts:

- Suggestion: "Hovering over the map icon in the top-right corner should reveal a satellite view icon"
- No such icon exists. I hovered over every icon on the page.
- Suggestion: "Click on question mark-icon on bottom-right"
- No such icon exists.
- Suggestion: "Click on Earth (bottom left corner)"
- Brings up 'Earth' and 'Map', no 'Satellite' option.
- Suggestion: "Google Maps may default to Lite mode for older browsers and operating systems"
- Unfortunately I have the latest browser and operating system. Temporary solution may be to use the 'preview' link instead of going to maps.google.com.
- Suggestion: "in the lower-right corner of the white box"..."tiny almost invisible down arrow" ... "click the sat icon"
- No down arrow exists in any white boxes.  Couldn't find any "sat" icon.
- Suggestion: Use Bing.
- (really?)

Update:

- Two temporary solutions seem to be:

  - Use Bing.  Unfortunately Bing's imagery is low resolution for this area and seems to be out of date, also I don't like the interface. These features used to be available at maps.google.com, are they gone for good?
  - I found a temporary alternative link that at least restores satellite imagery (no birds-eye though).  Rather than "http://maps.google.com/", go to "https://www.google.com/maps/preview/?force=canvas".  This disables 'Earth', but also disables other features, and I assume this link is temporary.  Any better way?

Answer (score 2):

I think I've figured this out!

1. Go to the hamburger menu at the top left, choose "Earth". The left-side menu will disappear, and the 3D images view will appear.
2. Go to the hamburger menu again. Under "Earth" there are now 2 items: 3D on and Labels on.
3. Click 3D on. It will toggle 3D to off.
4. ...
5. Rejoice.

Answer (score -2):

Upper left menu icon, then click 3D to turn 3D off or on.  When off, appears to be the satellite mode.